# $out ,$projection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i want to save records in a new collection using either $out or $merge.

```
     **/////collection 2- reservationdeatils////**
         "_id":ObjectId("5e4a898947363e964a886420"),
         "phoneNo" : 98765#####,
         "name" : "name1",
         "userId":ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"),
         "approversId":ObjectId("5e1efad268c3c811c83263cd")
         "bookedForDate":ISODate("2020-02-20T07:23:36.130Z"),
         "bookingDetails" : [
                    {    "_id" : ObjectId("5e44f471d1868d2a54aac12d"),
                         "seatsBooked" : 15,
                         "floorId" : "#IKE01",
                      },
                    {   "_id" : ObjectId("5e44f471d1868d2a54aac12c"),
                        "seatsBooked" : 35,
                        "floorId" : "#HKE04",
                    }
                 ],
     **/////collection 2-priceDetails////**
          {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5e1efb0168c3c811c83263ce"),
           "floorId" : "#IKE01",
           "weekday" : "monday",
            "pricePoint" : 589,
         }
         {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5e2694db54e532a4eb92b477"),
           "floorId" : "#IKE02",
           "weekday" : "thursday",
          "pricePoint" : 699
         }
        {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5e2694f954e532a4eb92b478"),
         "floorId" : "#HKE04",
         "weekday" : "monday",
         "pricePoint" : 579
        }
      **/////collection 3- discount////**
        {
        "_id" :  ObjectId("5e427de64617181a4ce38893"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"), 
        "approversId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
        "floorId" : "#IKE01",
        "weekday" : "monday",
        "discount" : 20%,
       },
       {
        "_id" :  ObjectId("5e4281e7fec2e01a4c60b406"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"), 
        "approversId" : ObjectId("5e1efad268c3c811c83263cd"),
        "floorId" : "#IKE01",
        "weekday" : "monday",
        "discount" : 24%,
     }
```

Now below is the query i have tried :

```
     db.reservationdeatils.aggregate([
    {
       '$match': {
          'approverId': ObjectId('5e1efad268c3c811c83263cd'),
          'userId': ObjectId('5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc'),
          'bookedForDate': ISODate("2020-02-11T18:30:00Z"),
        }
     },
     {
      '$unwind': {
          'path': '$bookingDetails',
       },
     }, 
       {
        $lookup:
         {
          from: 'priceDetails',
          let: { floorId: '$bookingDetails.floorId' },
          pipeline: [
              {
                  $match: {
                      weekday: 'monday',
                      $expr: {
                          $eq: ["$floorId", "$$floorId"]
                      }
                  }
              }
          ], as: 'priceDetails'
      }
  },
  { '$unwind': '$priceDetails' },
    {
      $lookup:
      {
          from: 'discount',
          let: { floorId: '$bookingDetails.floorId' },
          pipeline: [
              {
                  $match: {
                      weekday: 'monday',
                      $expr: {
                          $eq: ["$floorId", "$$floorId"]
                      }
                  }
              }
          ], as: 'discounts'
      }
  },
  { '$unwind': '$discounts' },

  {
      '$group': {
          '_id': {
              'floorId': '$bookingDetails.floorId',
              'date': '$bookedForDate',
              'price': '$priceDetails.pricePoint',
              'discount': '$discounts.discount'
          },
          'seatsBooked': {
              '$sum': '$bookingDetails.seatsBooked'
          },
       }
   },
     {
      '$project': {
            'amount': {
              '$multiply':
                   [ 
                     '$seatsBooked',
                        {'$subtract': 
                              ['$_id.pricePoint',
                                 { '$multiply': 
                                   ['$_id.pricePoint', 
                                      { '$divide': 
                                        ['$_id.discount', 100] 
                                   }] 
                               }]
                            }]
                         },
                     },
                   },
      {
          $group: {
           _id: null,
            totalAmount: {
            $sum: "$amount"
          }
      }
  },
    {
      '$project': {
          _id:0,
          totalAmount:1,
          bookedForDate:1,
          'floorId':'$priceDetails.floorId'
       }  
     },{'$merge':'invoice'}
  ]).pretty()
```

i have been able to achieve the totalAmount but what i want to achieve is that **i want to save these fields into "invoice" collection "userId","approversId","floorId","sum","totalSum","bookedForDate","name"** BUT 1:whenever i use $out instead of $merge the previous document gets replaces which i dont want, 2: if i use $merge everytime i run the query a new document is created and that too only with `_id:ObjectId(5e4a899c47363e964a88642f),totalBill:####` these fields , any suggestion how can i achieve this

Comment: if you are using MongoDB v4.2 you can make use of [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set) to update in MongoDB.

Comment: @– vikscool yes its v4.2 but $set , is it gonna create a new collection and where in my query should i use it or u meant i should structure another query to update it

Comment: When you used the stage `$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$bookingDetails" }` you wiped out all of the other data except seatsBooked and floorId.  You will need to rework the pipeline to keep the data in order to have it in the final document.

Comment: @joe yes u r right but i if i donot use this stage` $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$bookingDetails" }` then i am unable to fetch floorId from bookingDetails array object , if you can suggest what can i change in my query, i think it will resolve my issue

Comment: @joe i have just edited my query in my question please have a look at it but projection is still not working , only totalAmount is getting projected

Comment: when you group by `_id:null` you collapse the entire stream to a single document. I'm not really sure what you are expecting to see after that.

Comment: @joe yes u r right but if i donot group id by null then i will not be able to calculate "totalAmount" because prior to that i am getting total of against individual floorId and wanted to calculate the sum of all the floorId's , so i gotta tackle this issue somehow either i should restructure my whole query and if u can suggest something or i should try to save the required fileds some othey way.. any suggestions??

Comment: Take a look at `$facet`for handling multiple pipelines on the same stream of documents

Answer (score 0):

You are going in a good direction you just need to look at the `$group` aggregation.

One more thing I have used the discount as `int` value, not in percentage.

`"discount" : 24`

I have updated the query:

```
db.reservationdeatils.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"),
    "approversId" : ObjectId("5e1efad268c3c811c83263cd"),
    "bookedForDate" : ISODate("2020-02-20T07:23:36.130Z")
   }
},
{
 $unwind: {
     path: "$bookingDetails",
  },
}, 
{
 $lookup:
  {
   from: "priceDetails",
   let: { floorId: "$bookingDetails.floorId" },
   pipeline: [
       {
           $match: {
               weekday: "monday",
               $expr: {
                   $eq: ["$floorId", "$$floorId"]
               }
           }
       }
   ], 
   as: "priceDetails"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$priceDetails" 
},
{
 $lookup:
 {
     from: "discount",
     let: { floorId: "$bookingDetails.floorId" },
     pipeline: [
         {
             $match: {
                 weekday: "monday",
                 $expr: {
                     $eq: ["$floorId", "$$floorId"]
                 }
             }
         }
     ], 
     as: "discounts"
 }
}
,
{ 
  $unwind: "$discounts" 
}
,
{
 $group: {
     "_id": {
         "floorId": "$bookingDetails.floorId",
         "date": "$bookedForDate",
         "price": "$priceDetails.pricePoint",
         "discount": "$discounts.discount"
     },
     "price":{
      $first:"$priceDetails.pricePoint"
     },
     "discount":{
      $first:"$discounts.discount"
     },
     "seatsBooked": {
         $sum: "$bookingDetails.seatsBooked"
     },
  }
}
,
{
$project: {
  "amount": {
    $multiply:
      [
        "$seatsBooked",
        {
          $subtract:[
            "$price",
            {
              $multiply:[
                "$price",
                {
                  $divide:[
                    "$discount",
                    100
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  },
},
}
,
{
 $group: {
  "_id": null,
   "totalAmount": {
   $sum: "$amount"
   }
  }
},
{
 $project: {
     "_id":0,
     "totalAmount":1,
     "bookedForDate":1,
     "floorId":"$priceDetails.floorId"
  }  
},
{
  $out:"invoice"
}
]).pretty()
```

This will help you.